# tmux status bar config

Tags: tmux

Anyone know where this is located?

I tried the usual directories that macports uses and there's nothing in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate configuration file for *tmux*’s status line. The `set-option` command can be used to configure the session options (those whose names start with `status`); see the Options section of [*tmux(1)*](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1). To change the default value for all sessions, you will likely want to use `set-option -g …` so that your configuration will apply to all sessions that have not locally overridden the global defaults.

You can make configuration changes at any time in any of several different ways:

- Press C-b (your prefix key, if you have redefined it), then `:` to type commands directly to *tmux*.
- Issue *tmux* commands at the shell.
- Put them in a file and type C-b then `:source-file /path/to/file` or
  issue `tmux source-file /path/to/file` at a shell.

Usually, you record such configuration changes in a `.tmux.conf` file in your home directory. You can, however, specify a replacement configuration file with the `-f` command line option when starting a new server (you have to exit all your existing sessions to restart the server — or start it under a different socket with `-L` or `-S`).

There is also a system-wide configuration file (it is loaded before the one in your home directory); the default location is `/etc/tmux.conf`, but MacPorts changes it to `/opt/local/etc/tmux.conf`. The system-wide configuration file is always loaded for all users, so you should be very careful about what you put in it.